# C Programming for 8051: SFR directions as arguments

Tags: c, 8051, keil

I'm currently making a very simple Tic-Tac-Toe game with an AT89C51RC2 and I am having issues getting the button input right.

Basically, the input is a 3x3 Button Matrix which I want to utilize by scanning through the rows with a pulse while checking the columns for a connection; pretty basic. However, the way I wanted to do this was by making a unique *scroll* method that received the row parameter and set it to HIGH accordingly.

I already have

```
sbit R1 = P1^0;
```

all through the needed inputs, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Then, on my main method, I run something like

```
while(TRUE)
{
    scroll(R1);
}
```

which is named scroll, I have this

```
void scroll (bit P)
{
   P = HIGH; //Sets the row being checked to HIGH (HIGH is already defined as a 1). Same goes with the aformentioned TRUE
   ...
}
```

So, this is not working. I know I'm not doing this right, but I had to start somewhere. Is what I am attempting to do possible? Sending a single Pin adress as an overload for a method? If so, what datatype should it be? I was juggling between char and bit but I can't settle.

I hope my question is understandable! If not, I will gladly elaborate and maybe post all the code (although it is quite messy). Thanks, everyone, in advance!

Comment: What do you think `P1^0` does?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, it probably does what he thinks it does. It's a compiler extension for referencing the bit addressable range of memory in the 8051.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I could expand your code snippets to look like this:

```
sbit R1 = P1^0;
sbit R2 = P1^1;
sbit R3 = P1^2; 

while(TRUE)
{
    scroll(R1);
    scroll(R2);
    scroll(R3);
}
```

(Your `scroll` function remains as is). You are trying to define one function that you can call multiple times, passing in a different pin to assert each time you call the function.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a way to do exactly what you want to do, because you may not define `sbit`s in a function, either as locals or parameters. I'm sure there's a non-intuitive way to do it in inline assembly with the `SETB` and `CLR` instructions (maybe someone else can chime in), but with Keil the C compiler alone it is a no go.

Instead, perhaps you could make a helper function to do the pin assignment. That would let you do something like this:

```
void setRow(char whichRow, bit whatValue)
{
    switch (whichRow)
    {
        case 1:
            R1 = whatValue;
            break;
        case 2:
            R2 = whatValue;
            break;
        case 3:
            R3 = whatValue;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void scroll (char row)
{
    setRow(row, HIGH); //Sets the row being checked to HIGH (HIGH is already defined as a 1). Same goes with the aformentioned TRUE    
    ...
}
```

And then in your main:

```
while(TRUE)
{
    scroll(1);
    scroll(2);
    scroll(3);
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I tried to use sbit as parameter and it wasn't working. It has been pointed out that pointers don't work either, so I guess I will have to hard code it. Your switch statement is a good recommendation, but I think it'll be less lines of code if I just hard code it. It's only three rows, after all. Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

I saw you we're using Keil (really good 8051 compiler IMO). THis compiler gives you a header file for the MCU you are using, which already declares individual bit's of a port to access each of them [on Keil page dedicated to Atmel's family of 8051 compiler.](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/c51/atmel/at89c51rc2.h)

(AT89C51RC2 Keil's webpage http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/3681.htm)

That way, accessing each of the SFR of your chip will be way easier then re-defining them (UART, TIMER, etc).

Usually, a compiler which support's a chip will develop a header file for it's customers.

You can then, after including this header file in your project, access a bit this way :

```
unsigned char ucBTN = P1_0; //ucBTN equals P1_0 value;
```

It's, most of the time, the same for every 8051 you'll use, as they use the same "CORE" architecture.

Comment: I'll try using specific header's next time. I used REG51X.h becau e it was what I learned in school, AT89C51X.h or something). I definitely have to try the specific headers (I think it's AT. Thank you for your recommendation.